# Why entropy is more than 1 in Python?

Tags: python, math

I have a graph degree list `degrees` size of 10000 (e.g.: [1, 14, 4, 14, 6, 1 ...]. I am trying to calculate entropy of this list by this way:

Firstly, I am finding probability of each unique value in list:

```
uniqueDegreeList = list(set(degrees))

a = 0
for i in uniqueDegreeList:
    p = degrees.count(i) / len(degrees)
    print(p)
    a += p
```

Output:

```
0.5054494550544946
0.24577542245775422
0.12188781121887811
0.06379362063793621
0.031596840315968405
0.0150984901509849
0.007799220077992201
0.0034996500349965005
0.0024997500249975004
0.0010998900109989002
0.0008999100089991
0.00039996000399960006
0.00019998000199980003
```

And:

```
print(a)
>> 1.0
```

This part is working. Then I am trying to find entropy of list:

```
S = 0
for i in uniqueDegreeList:
    p = degrees.count(i) / len(degrees)
    S -= p * math.log(p, 2)
```

And when I print `S` I get `1.99`. Entropy should not be more than 1, why I get 1.99?

Comment: You don't want `len(degrees)` in the denominator. You'll want `sum(degrees.count)`, or samething like it.

Comment: `Entropy should not be more than 1`. Where did you read this?

Comment: Why do you expect the entropy to be no larger than 1? I see no reason for such an expectation. After all your sequence is not a sequence of binary digits but over a larger set of symbols, so each sample can be expected to carry considerable amounts of information.

Comment: @AjayDabas maybe I mixed it with physics, so it can be more than 1?

Comment: @MvG so, it can be more than 1 and everything is right, sir?

Comment: Yes, it can be more than one.

Comment: Depends on what you want. Entropy per character (cell, unit, ...) or the entropy of the array as a whole. But you allways can normalize.